# how to get two jquery script work good in one page

Tags: jquery

i have two script for menu navbar and tab sidebar it work good but when i add slideshow KenBurner the two script navbar and tab sidebar not work but slideshow work good...

and the three script:

script navbar menu:

```
$("#navmen ul, #topnav ul, .menu-xitem .xitem1 #labelnew").removeClass("hidden");
$("#navmen li, #topnav li").hoverTimeout(100, function () {
    $(this).children("ul").filter(":not(:animated)").slideDown()
}, 500, function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp(800, "easeInExpo")
});
$("#navmen li.dgnssub").hoverTimeout(100, function () {
    $(this).parent("ul").css("overflow", "visible")
}, 500, function () {
    $(this).parent("ul").css("overflow", "visible")
});
$(".menu-xitem .xitem1").hoverTimeout(100, function () {
    $("#labelnew", this).filter(":not(:animated)").slideDown()
}, 500, function () {
    $("#labelnew", this).slideUp(800, "easeInExpo")
});
$("ul#topnav").clone().appendTo("#navmobitop");
$("ul#navmen").clone().appendTo("#navmobi");
$("#navmobi ul, #navmobitop ul").removeAttr("id");
$("#mobilenavtop").toggle(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#navmobitop .topmen").slideDown();
    return false
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $("#navmobitop .topmen").slideUp();
    return false
});
$("#mobilenav").toggle(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#navmobi .menunav").slideDown();
    return false
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $("#navmobi .menunav").slideUp();
    return false
});
$("#navmobitop li, #navmobi li").hoverTimeout(100, function () {
    $(this).children("ul").filter(":not(:animated)").slideDown()
}, 500, function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp(800, "easeInExpo")
});
```

and tab sidebar script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabmeslect li:first").addClass("selected");
    $("#sideme > div").hide();
    $("#sideme > div:first").show();
    $("#tabmeslect a").click(function () {
        $("#tabmeslect li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        var a = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#sideme > div:visible").hide();
        $(a).fadeToggle(1000);
        return false
    })
});
```

and the slideshow problem from this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery('.bannercontainer').kenburn({
        thumbWidth: 50,
        thumbHeight: 50,
        thumbAmount: 4,
        thumbStyle: "both",
        thumbVideoIcon: "off",
        thumbVertical: "bottom",
        thumbHorizontal: "center",
        thumbXOffset: 0,
        thumbYOffset: 40,
        bulletXOffset: 0,
        bulletYOffset: -16,
        hideThumbs: "on",
        touchenabled: 'on',
        pauseOnRollOverThumbs: 'off',
        pauseOnRollOverMain: 'on',
        preloadedSlides: 2,
        timer: 7,
        debug: "off",
        googleFonts: 'Oswald',
        googleFontJS: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js'
    });
    });
```

Comment: Please format those first two scripts.. I can't read a one line file and have it make sense without hurting myself.

Comment: `$.noConflict();` there's your problem

Comment: The only reason to use noConflict is if you are running more than one version of jQuery or are reserving the $ for another library. What exactly is the problem?